# What is recommended way to get top N RDD (key,value) pair in the form of another RDD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

When we want the result back to the Spark's context the task can be done by using take ordered. I extend this idea by calling **parallelize** function to push the result to cluster as shown below:

```java
JavaPairDStream<Integer, String> filteredPair = pairDStream.transformToPair(
    new Function<JavaPairRDD<Integer, String>, JavaPairRDD<Integer, String>>() {
        public JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> call(JavaPairRDD <Integer, String> pairRDD) throws Exception {
            List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> topList = pairRDD.takeOrdered(10);
            return ssc.sparkContext().parallelizePairs(topList);
        }
    });
```

What bother me is that I think only RDD-transformation function should be expected inside the **transformToPair**. By mixing actions function with the transformation, does it destroy laziness of the transformation?

Comment: Could you explain how do you use it? I mean RDD with ten elements doesn't look like a particularly useful thing.

Comment: Thank you zero323. I try to use top ten key-value pairs to filter another RDD whose the size may be big. Example of this --> "Only process tweets which contain top ten popular twitter hashtags based on their count for every 60-minute window"